# updating rows where a datetime column is outside 9-5

Tags: mysql, sql

So for example

I have a table called checkins (id, user_id, checked_in, checked_out, status)

The columns checked_in and checked_out are datetime. Is it possible for a query to update status column to 0, if checked_in OR checked_out is outside the range of 9am-5am.

Example values 
2015-05-28 13:12:42 (inside)
2015-05-28 08:12:42 (outside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE checkins
SET status = 0
WHERE HOUR(checked_in) NOT BETWEEN 9 AND 17 
  OR HOUR(checked_out) NOT BETWEEN 9 AND 17
```